# Autofill a username and password

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I would like to be able to click a link in Website A that will autofill a username and password into Website B.

Can anybody provide me some ideas how to do this with JavaScript or PHP?

Many thanks!

Comment: I am going to mention the potential security risks of copying the password field, particularly if your solution involves passing it as a url parameter.  Are you sure of the credentials of the user at Site A? Does your security policy specify transmissions of passwords?  An alternative solution may be to pass a credential token instead of a username and password.

Comment: Are you after [Single Sign-On](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on)?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean by your question. Have you tried looking at [OpenSocial](http://code.google.com/apis/opensocial/) or [OpenID](http://openid.net/)?

Comment: Thanks for your response Nican. I'm not sure that that will help me :(

I have a client who has only one login to a site they subscribe to.

All of their staff use this one login to access that site.

I need to be able to link from their website (website A) and have the login fields on website B (the site they subscribe to) automatically filled in when they land on that page.

Possible?

Comment: @matchstic, nope, impossible.

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to edit website B, you can try to add a query string contains username and password to link and on website B get them from url and echo into input field's value attribute.

```
#Sample url on website A:
http://www.example.com/?username=admin&password=1234

#Simple sample form on website B:
<form>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['username']; ?>" />
    <input type="password" value="<?php echo $_GET['password']; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: +1 but,should encrpt/decrpt the username,password before/after passing.

Answer (score 0):

As someone else mentioned before the cleanest solution is to use a credential token.

1. User logs in on Site A.
2. Site A inserts a credential token in Site B's database - either by directly contacting the database of Site B or by calling a URL or an API in the background. This credential token will contain a unique token identifier (usually a long string, possibly obtained from md5-ing something) and the username and password of the user on Site B.
3. When the user is presented links to Site B on Site A all of them end with &token=123456789abcdef0
4. When the user arrives on Site B and the URL contains the token mentioned, username and password are extracted from the token in Site B's database and prefilled in the login box.

Tweak this to your liking.